# Electrode potential of Br2/HBr half cell

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, reference-request

I am wondering if it is possible to find the electrode potential of such a half cell:

$$\ce{Br2 (l) + 2 e- <=> 2Br-(g)}$$

The standard electrode potential is for $\ce{Br-(aq)}.$ However, is it possible to measure such a half cell? And if yes, will I be able to find this value from a reputable source?

Comment: Not all redox potentials are measurable, but they can be formally calculated from reaction Gibbs energy with involved SHE half cell.

Comment: Half cell potential of $\ce{Br2/Br^-}$ has a standard redox potential equal to +$1.06$ V. It can be measured if this half-cell has a platinum electrode which is coupled with any other half-cell.

Comment: @Maurice Have you noticed **(g)**?

Comment: @Poutnik. I have not seen the (g). But it is impossible to have a lonely ion in the gaseous state after such a half-reaction. So this question does not have any meaning